# numpy: indexing 1d array with multidimensional index

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-indexing

How do I index a lower dimensional data array with a higher dimensional index array?

E.g.: Given a 1d data array and a 2d index array:

```
data = np.array([11,12,13])
idx = np.array([[0,1],
                [1,2])
```

I would like to get a 2d data array:

```
np.array([[11,12],
          [12,13]])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy in Python / NumPy, thanks to the [advanced Numpy indexing system](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html), you just use your indexing as the slicing, e.g. `data[idx]`.

```
data = np.array([11,12,13])
idx = np.array([[0,1],
                [1,2]])

# this will produce the correct result
data[idx]
# array([[11, 12],
#        [12, 13]])
```

Comment: i had tried this, but now realize that what was missing was ensuring that the index array has to be int32.

Comment: I used this to assign a 1D array with 2D array index... It's works too., but I don't know why...